# Question from Herstein's Topics in Algebra on Sylow theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $P$ be a $p$-Sylow subgroup of a finite group $G$, and suppose $a, b$ are in the center of $P$. Suppose further that there is an $x$ in $G$ such that $a = xbx^{-1}$. Then there exists $y$ in $N(P)$ with $a = yby^{-1}$, where $N(P)$ is the normalizer of $P$.

I've been working on this problem since last night and have made basically no progress. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Show that both $P$ and $xPx^{-1}$ are subgroups of $C_G(a)$, the  centralizer of $a$ in $G$, and hence are $p$-Sylow subgroups of $C_G(a)$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I don't really know where to go from here. How do I relate this group to N(P)?

Comment: Okay, so then $P$ and $xPx^{-1}$ are conjugate in the centralizer, so there exists $y$ in the centralizer with $P = yxPx^{-1}y^{-1}$. Therefore $yx$ is in the normalizer, but since $y$ commutes with $a$ we have $a = xbx^{-1} = yxbx^{-1}y^{-1}$. Many thanks!